# Why are the instance variables not set on the class using attr_accessor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried to call an existing class using `FileSearchable.new(current_user, params[:keyword]).call` but I am getting the error, `undefined method 'where' for nil:NilClass` on `my_folders = my_folders.where("name ILIKE ?", filter) unless filter.blank?`

The class is below

```
class FileSearchable

  attr_accessor :user, :my_files, :my_folders, :shared_folders, :shared_files, :filter

  def initialize(user, filter)
    @user = user
    @my_folders = user.folders
    @my_files = user.user_documents
    @shared_folders = user.shared_folders
    @shared_files = user.user_documents
    @filter = filter
  end

  def apply_search_params
    my_folders = my_folders.where("name ILIKE ?", filter) unless filter.blank?
  end
end
```

I am not sure why the `my_folders` variable is not being set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a very common gotcha. You create a local variable `my_folders` which shadows your accessor. Call the method explicitly:

```
  def apply_search_params
    self.my_folders = my_folders.where("name ILIKE ?", filter) unless filter.blank?
  end
```

Or assign the instance var directly (like you do in the initializer)

```
  def apply_search_params
    @my_folders = my_folders.where("name ILIKE ?", filter) unless filter.blank?
  end
```

But this somewhat defeats the purpose of attr_accessor. Why generate a writer and then not use it?

Comment: omg. omg. omg. I guess I bumped my head when I woke up this morning.